# Getting null values on the arrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I am storing my jSon array data in `ArrayList<Model>`. I want to use this `ArrayList<Model>` in other class so I created a method which returns the ArrayList. But always I m getting null.

**Class**

```
public class SearchJobAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String response;
    Context c;
    SearchModel data;
    ArrayList<SearchModel> values;

    public SearchJobAsync(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute ();
        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "Please Wait...", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        values = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();

        super.onPostExecute (s);
        if (!s.trim ().contains ("Table")) {
            Crouton.makeText ((android.app.Activity) c, "Nothing found", Style.INFO).show ();
        } else {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                    values.add (data);
                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject (i);
                        data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                        values.add (data);

                    }

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }

        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "", false);
        Intent i = new Intent (c, SearchJobListActivity.class);
        c.startActivity (i);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... s) {
        response = HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/FindJobForVendor").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "34588A34-E969-4723-84FE-E5409B66A5B7" + "&Job_Code=" + "&Job_Category=1" + "&Exp_Years_From=0" + "&Exp_Months_From=0" + "&Exp_Years_To=0" + "&Exp_Months_To=0").body ();
        response = response.replaceAll ("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll ("\n", "");
        Log.e ("Search Jobs", "" + response);
        return response;
    }

    public ArrayList<SearchModel> getList(){
        return values;
    }
}
```

Class where i am using arraylist

```
public class SearchJobList extends ListFragment {
    private View view;
    private ListView lvSearchJobs;
    private ArrayList<SearchModel> data;
    SearchJobCustomList customList;
    SearchJobAsync searchJobAsync;
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.search_job_lists, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        c = getActivity ();
        lvSearchJobs = (ListView) getActivity ().findViewById (android.R.id.list);
        data = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();
        searchJobAsync = new SearchJobAsync (c);
        data = searchJobAsync.getList ();

        customList = new SearchJobCustomList (c, data);
        setListAdapter (customList);

    }
}
```

Class where i m usring .execute() method

```
public class SearchJobsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View view;
    private Spinner spCategory;
    private Button btSearch;
    private Spinner spToYrs;
    private Spinner spFromMonths;
    private Spinner spFromYrs;
    private Spinner spToMonths;
    private EditText etJobCode;
    private String[] yrsArray, monthArray, professionArray;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> toYrs, toMonths, profession;
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.search_jobs_frag, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    private void initialize() {

        c = getActivity ();
        spCategory = (Spinner) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.sp_category);
        btSearch = (Button) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.bt_search);
        spToYrs = (Spinner) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.sp_to_yrs);
        spFromMonths = (Spinner) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.sp_from_months);
        spFromYrs = (Spinner) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.sp_from_yrs);
        spToMonths = (Spinner) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.sp_to_months);
        etJobCode = (EditText) getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.et_job_code);
        btSearch.setOnClickListener (this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        initialize ();
        spinnerSetup ();
    }

    private void spinnerSetup() {

        //for to/from yrs

        yrsArray = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Experience_yrss);
        toYrs = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.spinner_textview, yrsArray);
        toYrs.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        spToYrs.setAdapter (toYrs);
        spFromYrs.setAdapter (toYrs);


        // for to/from months
        monthArray = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Experience_months);
        toMonths = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.spinner_textview, monthArray);
        toMonths.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        spToMonths.setAdapter (toMonths);
        spFromMonths.setAdapter (toMonths);


        //for category

        professionArray = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Profession);
        Arrays.sort (professionArray, 1, professionArray.length);
        profession = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.spinner_textview, professionArray);
        profession.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        spCategory.setAdapter (profession);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SearchJobAsync searchJobAsync = new SearchJobAsync (c);
        searchJobAsync.execute ();
    }
}
```

In `getList()` method I am returning the values but its always showing null.

Comment: it seems that values is null.

Comment: nah i have added the data from jSon array.

Comment: it seems that items in values are null. Try printing the values in Log to make sure the data is fetched ..

Comment: are you sure it's not null? debug it.

Comment: values is initialized in onPostExecute(), so you should only call getList() after the task has finished. How do you make sure this is the case?

Comment: so wat can i do please help

Comment: why you are using getList()? i see you are starting SearchJobListActivity onPostExecute() so when do you call getList? and why?

Comment: please post code/names of activities where you are accessing this ArrayList and activity from where you are calling AsyncTask

Comment: Why `Intent i = new Intent (c, SearchJobListActivity.class);` inside AsyncTask??? Consider moving it to the activity.

Comment: @silwar i did it pls check it

Comment: @mek what d problem in using it in async task???

Comment: It may not create execution problem but the populated list of your by `SearchJobAsync` will not be visible to user. Just after the task is completed, it will navigates to `SearchJobListActivity.` u may do this when the user selects from the list. In addition, u havn't called `execute()` on the SearchJobAsync; excution of the task will not start until u call execute().

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access before `onPostExecute()` is excuted, the list will be null. Because it is not yet initialized. So, make sure the task is fully completed before trying to access the list.

As you are showing progress, you better pass your local `List<SearchModel>` reference to constructor of the `SearchJobAsync`. This reference will have value only after the dialog is hidden. 
Thus add a constructor like:

```
public SearchJobAsync(Context c, List<SearchModel> values) {
    this.c = c;
    this.values=values;
}
```

And in your activity

```
List<SearchModel> myListVar;
new SearchJobAsync(MyActivity.this, myListVar);
```

Comment: but i m also using the constructor to execute my async task

Comment: the constructor is different here. it accepts list in addition to context.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getList` method before the task is finished (the method `onPostExecute` is called after the task is finished). You have to notify your context (Activity, fragment) when the list is ready.

Comment: You can pass your Fragment in the constructor of your AsyncTask. `public SearchJobAsync(SearchJobsFragment f)` then define the callback method in your fragment for example.

Answer (score 0):

Issue lies in following lines

```
 data = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();
 searchJobAsync = new SearchJobAsync (c);
 data = searchJobAsync.getList ();
```

You are not calling execute() method for AsyncTask like below

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Without this onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute methods will not invoke. This is reason you are getting data as null.

One more suggestion, in your onPostExecute(), you are calling startActivity() method

```
 Intent i = new Intent (c, SearchJobListActivity.class);
    c.startActivity (i);
```

but you want value of ArrayList in SearchJobList Fragment. Once AsyncTask gets executed successfully, new activity will be shown on screen. You need to work on this.

Check documentation of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: but sir i am calling Async.execute in different Activity.The activity which i posted ,i nly want the Arraylist

Comment: you are executing one object of AsyncTask at one place and you are accessing value from another object. Its completely fair if you are getting null value for data. Please check data value after searchJobAsync.execute (); in onclick method if it is getting null or not

Comment: Yes sir i had debugged my application,and i was getting data in onPost () method

Comment: not int onPostExecute method. in you onClick method of button after searchJobAsync.execute (); put data = searchJobAsync.getList (); and check if value of data is null or not

Comment: I did like this but nothing is showing.

    public void onClick(View view) {
        SearchJobAsync searchJobAsync = new SearchJobAsync (c);
        searchJobAsync.execute ();
        new SearchJobAsync.getArrayList () {
            @Override
            public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data) {
                Log.e ("data",""+data);
            }
        };

    }